# What's the meaning of "taking someone up for the downs"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I was watching a British period drama based on Thomas Hardy's Tess of the d'Urbervilles. Somewhere in the movie, a very poor family lose their horse, a lifeline for the family, in an accident. After the animal's burial, the mother of the family says to her children, "Well, we must take you up for the downs." What does she exactly mean?
By the way, the words before or after this sentence are not related.

Comment: Who gets hurt in the tragic accident? Will there be a funeral, perhaps with music, guns, a parade? And then a burial?

Comment: What drama was it? What episode? Could you have misheard?

Comment: Can you be sure she doesn't say we must take the ups and the downs?

Comment: I just added more details.

Comment: @Xanne, the family's horse is killed in the accident. And yes, the words are uttered after the animal's burial.

Comment: @Michael Harvey, it's a 1998 adaptation of Thomas Hardy's Tess of the d'Urbervilles. I'm sure I haven't misheard. I even checked an English subtitle.

Comment: The text of the book includes the line, shortly after the horse accident, “We must take the ups wi’ the downs, Tess,” said she; “and never could your high blood have been found out at a more called-for moment. You must try your friends. Do ye know that there is a very rich Mrs d’Urberville living on the outskirts o’ The Chase, who must be our relation? You must go to her and claim kin, and ask for some help in our trouble.”

Comment: There are amateur, non-official subtitles and scripts on the web for many films and TV programmes. They often contain errors and mishearings. Since they are often copied, it may seem like they have authority. This is not idiomatic English. I believe Xanne has it right.

Comment: Was it a race horse?

Comment: I found a copy of a subtitle file [here](https://www.opensubtitles.org/en/subtitles/3690100/tess-of-the-d-urbervilles-en), wherein I see that the very next utterance is ***But, Tess, never was your fine blood
found a more called-for moment.*** I don't have easy access to the original video, but that doesn't look like plausible English to me, even allowing for the "historical, regional, dialectal" context of the entire thing. Another thing I notice is the subtitle file is littered with instances of ***gonna*** (for *going to*) - which to me suggests "non-Anglophone manual transcription".
*

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's predicated on some kind of mistranscription - given that *The text of the book includes the line, shortly after the horse accident, “**We must take the ups wi’ the downs, Tess**”*

Comment: @GArthurBrown - It was a working horse on which the family depended for their livelihood.